# How to handle @Valid MethodArgumentNotValidException by @RestControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, rest

Helo,
I have a problem with testing controller that throws MethodArgumentNotValidException.

I have entity with validation annotation.

```
public class Tag extends ResourceSupport {
...
    @NotEmpty(message = "Tag name cannot be empty.")
    @NotNull(message = "Tag name cannot be empty.")
    private String name;
}
```

Controller with @Valid annotation for @RequestBody

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api/tags")
public class TagController {
    .......

    @PostMapping(value = "")
    public ResponseEntity<Tag> addNewTag(@Valid @RequestBody Tag tag) {
        Tag createdTag = tagService.saveOrUpdate(tag);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdTag, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

Now I want to test this conttroller with unit test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TagControllerTest {
     private MockMvc mockMvc;

     @Before
     public void setup() {
            JacksonTester.initFields(this, new ObjectMapper());
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(tagController).setControllerAdvice(new GlobalExceptionHandlerController()).build();
        }

    @Test
    public void shouldntAllowToSetTagNameEmpty() throws Exception {
        Tag tag1 = new Tag();

        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/tags").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(jsonTags.write(tag1).getJson()))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

   }
```

Global exception handling class is created this way.It is only as  example form internet.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status,
        WebRequest request) {

    String bodyOfResponse = ex.getMessage();
    return new ResponseEntity(bodyOfResponse, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Test is passing, as it only test status, but in console I have stack trace with error log

> org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: ..... default message [Tag name cannot be empty.]]

Is this correct that error stack trace appear in console log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation works fine,
this is a normal behavior, during tests, MockMvc print MvcResult details using

> PrintingResultHandler

so it will also print exceptions resolved through a HandlerExceptionResolver by calling **printResolvedException()**

check out [PrintingResultHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/PrintingResultHandler.html)